# Nodejs: Unexpected behaviour when piping chunked HTTP data to a file in OS X

Tags: node.js, express

I'm getting a weird issue when piping a chunked data from HTTP to a file in OS X.

When triggering the GET HTTP request that initiates the download, my server responds with the following headers:

```
< content-disposition: attachment; filename="resin-Rpi2-0.1.0-0.0.12.img"
< content-encoding: gzip
< content-type: application/octet-stream
< date: Wed, 06 May 2015 19:03:33 GMT
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< x-powered-by: Express
< transfer-encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
```

My code goes like this:

```
fs = require('fs')
request = require('request')

# If you want to try it by yourself, register to https://dashboard.resin.io
# create a Raspberry Pi application (note the id on the url)
# and get the token from the preferences page.
APPID = '...'
TOKEN = '...'
DEST = 'imagetest.img'

request
  url: "https://dashboard.resin.io/download?network=ethernet&wifiSsid=&wifiKey=&appId=#{APPID}"
  method: 'GET'
  gzip: true
  headers:
      Authorization: "Bearer #{TOKEN}"

.on 'data', (data) ->
  console.log(data)

.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(DEST))
```

If I run that script, I correctly get the initial chunks (corresponding to about 10MB of data) but the connection then suddenly ends, and no other event (close, end, etc) is triggered from any of the streams.

What's even more weird is that commenting out `gzip: true` leads to the desired behaviour (I of course get a *.img.gz file in that case), and it also works as expected if keeping the `gzip: true` and piping to `process.stdout` instead of to a file.

Also notice the issue is not reproducible on Ubuntu. It only seems to happen in OS X and Windows.

`cURL` also works as expected:

```
$ curl -H "Authorization: Bearer [token]" "https://dashboard.resin.io/download?network=ethernet&wifiSsid=&wifiKey=&appId=[appid]" -o image.img
```

I've proceeded to analyse the packet communication ([you can get the pcap here](http://filebin.net/5h4k576f6t/ResinImageDownloadIssue.pcap)):

I can see my IP is suddenly sending a ACK/FIN while the server is still sending me chunks:

```
Id = 2984
Source = 192.168.0.16
Destination = 52.4.102.97
Captured Length = 66
Packet Length = 66
Protocol = TCP
Date Received = 2015-05-06 18:11:36 +0000
Time Delta = 10.27246999740601
Information = 52264 -> 443 ([ACK, FIN], Seq=2137874087, Ack=3255859962, Win=10407)
```

Followed by a long loop of RST and ACK:

```
...
192.168.0.16 -> 52.4.102.97, 52264 -> 443 RST
52.4.102.97 -> 192.168.0.16, 443 -> 52264 ACK
...
```

And finally an agreed ACK, FIN from both sides.

What am I doing wrong? What's the correct way to expose/consume chunked HTTP data with `node-request` and `Express`?

Comment: I can reproduce your issue using node `0.12.2` and `0.11.16`, but in `0.10.38` your code works perfectly. Hope that's of some help.

Comment: @AndrewLavers Thanks for taking the time to test, that's highly appreciated. I was able to make it work by writing the chunks manually to  the destination stream (with `destination.write(data)` inside of the `data` listener) instead of piping, but I'm definitely still looking for an explanation.

Comment: I'd say it's worth a github issue

Comment: @AndrewLavers I've created an issue here: https://github.com/request/request/issues/1567.